# The material ui package refused to install

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm

C:\Users\User\Desktop\client4>**npm i @material-ui/icons**

npm ERR! code ERESOLVE

npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree

npm ERR!

npm ERR! While resolving: client4@0.1.0

npm ERR! Found: react@18.2.0

npm ERR! node_modules/react

npm ERR!   react@"^18.2.0" from the root project

npm ERR!

npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:

npm ERR! peer react@"^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0" from @material-ui/core@4.12.4

npm ERR! node_modules/@material-ui/core

npm ERR!   peer @material-ui/core@"^4.0.0" from @material-ui/icons@4.11.3

npm ERR!   node_modules/@material-ui/icons

npm ERR!     @material-ui/icons@"*" from the root project

npm ERR!

npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry

npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps

npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.

npm ERR!

npm ERR! See C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

npm ERR!     C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2022-06-21T23_42_51_581Z-debug-0.log

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that you are tring to use Material UI v4 with React 18.
Try to upgrade to Material UI v5.

```
npm install @mui/material@latest @emotion/react@latest @emotion/styled@latest
npm install @mui/icons-material@latest
```

**Update**

Or if you want to use the v4 (Which i don't reccomend):

```
npm install @mui/material @emotion/react @emotion/styled --legacy-peer-deps
npm install @mui/icons-material --legacy-peer-deps
```

Comment: how can i upgrade to Material UI v5

Comment: i will go for v5