# Having problems with Material UI installations and React v. 18.2

Tags: reactjs, npm, material-ui

I'm trying to experiment with Material UI but running into problems with React v.18.2. I need to import the following:

```
import { MuiThemeProvider, createTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles'
```

But when I run `npm install @material-ui/styles`, I get this error:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: zscratch@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react@18.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^18.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0" from @material-ui/styles@4.11.5
npm ERR! node_modules/@material-ui/styles
npm ERR!   @material-ui/styles@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

I have tried running the following, [per this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72708253/the-material-ui-package-refused-to-install), and they did install but that has not helped any:

```
npm install @mui/material@latest @emotion/react@latest @emotion/styled@latest
npm install @mui/icons-material@latest
```

Here are my dependencies.

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.10.0",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.0",
    "@fontsource/roboto": "^4.5.8",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.8.4",
    "@mui/material": "^5.10.1",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.3.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-geolocated": "^4.0.3",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
```

Bottom line: What do I need to do to be able to import what I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try **yarn**.

```
yarn add @material-ui/styles
```

Also you can install it by using --**force**.

```
npm i -f @material-ui/styles
```

It worked for me

Comment: Doing the force on npm worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try these React 18 MUI update commands

```
npm i @material-ui/core --legacy-peer-deps
npm i @mui/icons-material --legacy-peer-deps
npm i @mui/lab --legacy-peer-deps
npm i @mui/x-data-grid --legacy-peer-deps
npm i @mui/x-data-grid-generator --legacy-peer-deps
```